# Does the LEGO Star Wars Holiday X-Wing (4002019) contain any unique pieces?

Tags: piece-information, sets, set-modification

The 2019 LEGO Employee Gift 4002019 is a holiday-style Star Wars X-Wing Fighter.

[image]

From what I can tell, this set is based on [the current LEGO Star Wars X-Wing Fighter](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/x-wing-starfighter-75218), with some different colored pieces and a few extra models like Yoda's hut and sleigh.

[image]

Does this set contain any unique pieces (and thus likely as expensive as the set on BrickLink), or would it be possible to build this set by redesigning the current X-Wing set with pieces from my collection and/or other sets which are widely available? If it does contain unique pieces, what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking part inventory for this set on [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/sets/4002019-1/yuletide-squadron-xmas-wing-starfighter/#parts) I found following part to be unique:

[10169 - Minifigure, Utensil Sack / Bag with Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=10169#T=C) in Green

Review posted on [New Elementary](https://www.newelementary.com/2020/01/lego-x-wing-instructions-download-christmas-4002019.html?m=1) also suggest pilot's torso and legs are new/unique prints.

The rest seem to be released in other sets. Some parts are quite old or have been produced in small number of sets.

Comment: But when I click the link, it says the part was part of 38 sets...

Comment: @ThomasHirsch yes, this pieces has appeared in 38 sets in different colors. If you check the actual set [list](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=10169&in=S) you can see set+color combination for the part.